# How To Do This With Bluetooth Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Is there any way to detect when data send to another Bluetooth phone if data is a String, an Object or a File Image, Audio or Video etc...?

Normally, I convert them to `ByteArray` and send then listen data Bluetooth incoming from another device like this

```
val inputStream = socket.inputStream
val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
var bytes = 0
val bos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
while (true) {
    try {
        bytes = inputStream.read(buffer)
        // New Data Incoming

        // This is for case as Image File then convert to Bitmap 
        bos.write(buffer, 0, bytes)
        val img= bos.toByteArray()      

        // This is for case as text 
        var text = String(buffer).substring(0, bytes)

    } catch() 
}
```

If I combine 2 `ByteArray` together (Like I have a text: "SENDIMG:" + Byte Array of Image) then how can I listen that data when sent to another Bluetooth Device?

(I looked old questions how to combine 2 bytes array but there no way to listen that data as Incoming data Bluetooth)

(I saw document of Android Developer too, but document just seem like guide how to send simple text)

I thought I should send simple text to check event when I send text, image, video, or audio then handle if else. Is that right?

Comment: Assuming you are using Bluetooth LE, you may just use a second characteristic that you use to set the data type. For example, prior to reading the datum DATA, you read the TYPE characteristic, which is always an int, that you map 0 -> string, 1 -> image, or whatever you like

Comment: The reason i can't do that is when I send an image or an video data will send gradually data of video and image to other bluetooth device. Like sending text: I combine its with 1 + "sometext", But send a video it sent gradually data (long data and multiple time) of video and image to a image view , video view, there is no way to detect special character I want